# Making clickable areas on a 3D model in Three js

Tags: three.js

I'm creating a webpage for a new beer brand for gamers.

So far, I've created a spinning beer can in Three js. I found a GLTF model, made a texture, added lighting and reflections - all the simple basics - using Drei and Fiber.

What I would love to achieve right now, is to use the beer can as navigation for the page. So if you mouse over the logo on the face of the can, the logo should change color to indicate you can click it, and if you click it, something happens (let's say a modal opens). You can then spin the can around and click different parts of it (some text, an icon, the barcode, etc) to get different content.

I'm not sure how I would achieve this or approach this. I've had a couple of different thoughts:

1. Map up clickable areas on the model somehow. This didn't seem possible.
2. Make all the different clickable parts separate objects in the model. This seems like a ton of work, and I'd have to spend a lot of time learning Blender. The can model is pretty simple (used a free one from sketchfab.com for now).
3. Map up html-elements onto the can using `css3drenderer`. But I didn't find a way to bend it onto the can well, and it didn't seem like I could use the model for that.
4. Use many textures with alphas on top of each other on the can and somehow look for transparency on click for each layer. Didn't find any way to do this.

Any ideas on what techniques to use to achieve this? I've done game dev in Unity, but I'm new to Three js and WebGL, so it's really hard to know where to start searching.

Comment: Did you look at the [interactive examples](https://threejs.org/examples/?q=interactive)?

Comment: Yeah, I couldn't really figure anything out from them that would achieve the effect.

Comment: Take a look at my answer

Comment: @PetterSjöstrand, If my answer helped you, it would be great if you could accept it and upvote :)

Answer (score 0):

The common approach is to use [`raycasting`](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/core/Raycaster) to detect interaction with a model.

What you're really looking for is a [`hyperlink`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperlink/). Although you can't manually apply a [`hyperlink`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperlink/) to [`three.js`](https://threejs.org/), you can use [`THREE.Raycaster()`](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/core/Raycaster) as a loophole.

Once you determine that the model *was* clicked on, you just do the following to redirect the user:

```js
window.location.href = 'https://example.com/'
```

That should do it~

### EDIT:

Here is an example, based on my reply to your comment:

```js
if(intersects.length > 0){
    if(intersects[0] == model.children[2]){ //Second child
        window.location.href = 'https://example.com/'
    }
}
```

Comment: This requires the solution of splitting the model into separate models for each clickable bit, which is very undynamic. But so far seems to be the only option.

Comment: There *might* be a possible workaround. If you do `console.log(model)`, it should return as a `group`; you can find the `child` of the `group` with the logo on it (the one you want to be clickable), and check if that was clicked. For example, `model.children[1]` (if the second child is the logo). NOTE: THIS ONLY WORKS DEPENDING ON HOW YOUR MODEL WAS CREATED.

I have edited my answer too